# Vagrant ssh authentication failure on windows

Tags: windows, ssh, vagrant, virtualbox

I am trying to get Linux Ubuntu 32 bit box running on Windows VM Ware. I was following a course on UDACITY and they told me to install these software. I don't know much about how to run these software. I tried to find answers on Stack but it was all on different OS not Windows. I tried some edit also by enabling GUI and i also added Vagrant configure in Vagrantfile.

Having a problem with ssh authentication:

Error:

```
e2sn7cy@EMR-HZDEV08-003 /C/Users/e2sn7cy/fullstack/vagrant (master)
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty32' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 8000 => 1234 (adapter 1)
    default: 8080 => 8080 (adapter 1)
    default: 5000 => 4321 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

My Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.gui = true
end

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
end  
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "pg_config.sh"
  # config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty32"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 1234
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5000, host: 4321

end
```

My pg_config.sh

```
apt-get -qqy update
apt-get -qqy install postgresql python-psycopg2
apt-get -qqy install python-flask python-sqlalchemy
apt-get -qqy install python-pip
pip install bleach
pip install oauth2client
pip install requests
pip install httplib2
su postgres -c 'createuser -dRS vagrant'
su vagrant -c 'createdb'
su vagrant -c 'createdb forum'
su vagrant -c 'psql forum -f /vagrant/forum/forum.sql'

vagrantTip="[35m[1mThe shared directory is located at /vagrant\nTo access your shared files: cd /vagrant(B[m"
echo -e $vagrantTip > /etc/motd
```

Answer (score 0):

you can open the gui mode to see what happened in your virtual machine.

- do not change the default configuration, download a new box and use the default config
- if you want to use the python development environment, you can download a box including all python environment

Comment: Hey i used the default config only, i just edited two three lines and then again I changed the same but still it's not working. (https://www.udacity.com/wiki/ud197/install-vagrant) I have used this link to install.

Comment: Yeah i have opened my gui mode, its asking for uid and password but i dont know that

Comment: try user: root pwd: vagrant

Comment: uid vagrant pwd vagrant in my box.

Comment: yeah i am able to login with that but still is there any other way or ssh

Comment: download ssh and use command "vagrant ssh" or putty and host=127.0.0.1 port=2222

Comment: how to launch the gui ? whenever I try with vagrant ssh or putty, it launches the box in command line

Answer (score 0):

Try setting config.vm.boot_timeout to a higher value, default is 300. Like this:

```
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty32"
config.vm.boot_timeout = 600
```